# react-native open source projects not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

I'm trying to open some open source projects from GitHub but none of the projects worked, I have tried more than 10 apps and I'm getting errors in all of them. Here are some of the errors I got on RocketChat app.[this is the ios error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxS2E.png),
[Android error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DjR1.png),
[I cloned the app from this page](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative.git)

and this is another example of F8 app created by Facebook
[this is the android error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CWPH.png),
[I cloned the project from this page](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app.git)

Answer (score 0):

You need `npm i` after cloning the project.